# How can I add didDisplayCell delegate to UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift

I am well aware of willDisplay, but I need to know exactly when it's displayed.

Is there a way I can subclass UITableView so that I can use this?  It's absolutely necessary; I don't understand why Apple doesn't have this delegate.

Comment: I think you can use the willDisplayCell delegate only and check for indexPath.row - 1, so if willDisplayCell has indexPath.row 3 it means 2 cell is loaded.

Comment: @BharatModi your advice not looks nice. what if only one cell in table? what if we moving table in reverse direction?

Comment: @ShadowOf I agree. I have only one cell sometimes .

Comment: @TIMEX what do you want to use a "didDisplayCell" method for?

Comment: I'm wondering if subclassing the `UITableViewCell`, override the `didMoveToWindow` and tell then a custom delegate that would be called "didDisplayCell:" could do the trick.

Comment: Can you explain just a little what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Just an idea (I didn't try it), but have you tried to check the "visibleCells" or "indexPathsForVisibleRows" properties? These contain the table cells that are visible in the table view. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/visibleCells